# Show that a map f : (X,$\tau$) $\rightarrow$ (Y,$\tau_1$) is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(U)\in\tau$ , for every $U \in B_1$

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ and $(Y,\tau_1) $be topological spaces and $B_1$ a basis for the topology $\tau_ 1$. Show that a map $f : (X,\tau) \rightarrow (Y,\tau_1)$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(U)\in\tau$ , for every $U\in B_1$

I have already proved the "if part". Since the set in the basis is necessary open, I've no idea how to prove the "only if part". Please give me some ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:** Recall that every open set in $\tau_1$ is the union of basic open sets from $B_1$. Then recall that preimage and unions commute.

(Of course, if you can't recall one of these, or both, you should prove these things in full.)

Comment: Let $V\in\tau_1,V=\cup U_i$. Then $\cup f^{-1} (U_i)\in\tau$, right? I can't see how I can proceed to $f^{-1} (U_i)\in\tau$...

Comment: Have you used the assumption yet?

Comment: Ya, $f^{-1}(V)\in\tau$, $f^{-1}(\cup U_i)\in\tau$, then $\cup f^{-1}(U_i)\in\tau$.

Comment: But I still can't conclude $f^{-1} (U)\in\tau$.

Comment: Please state, here, explicitly what is the assumption that you started from. And what exactly is $U$.

Comment: Haha, I know what I was doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: It's important to remember your assumptions!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f^{-1}(U)$ is open  for all $U \in B_1$. Consider $ V \in \tau_{B_1}$.Then $V=\cup _{U \in B_2} U$ for some  $B_2 \subset B_1$

Now $f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}( \cup _{U \in B_2} U) = \cup_{U \in B_2} f^{-1}(U)$

Therefore $f^{-1}(U)$ is open implies $\cup_{U \in B_2} f^{-1}(U)$ is open